# select multiple columns from different tables and join in hive

Tags: join, hive, nosql

I have a hive table A with 5 columns, the first column(A.key) is the key and I want to keep all 5 columns. I want to select 2 columns from B, say B.key1 and B.key2 and 2 columns from C, say C.key1 and C.key2.  I want to join these columns with A.key = B.key1 and B.key2 = C.key1

What I want is a new external table D that has the following columns. B.key2 and C.key2 values should be given NULL if no matching happened.

```
A.key, A_col1, A_col2, A_col3, A_col4, B.key2, C.key2
```

What should be the correct hive query command? I got a max split error for my initial try.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
create external table D as
select A.key, A.col1, A.col2, A.col3, A.col4, B.key2, C.key2
from A left outer join B on A.key = B.key1 left outer join C on A.key = C.key2;
```

If not, could you post more info about the "max split error" you mentioned? Copy+paste specific error message text is good.

Comment: Your query is almost correct, except you need drop "external", it is not compatible with "as", this is what I wrote at the first try. After I drop it, it worked. Regarding the max split error, it is related to hadoop configuration, not related to the query.